# how to post html form to action method in cs

Tags: c#, sharepoint, user-controls, web-parts

I have a html form it should be post content to action("searchUser") in backend

user.ascx:

```
<form action="/searchUser" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
...
</form>
```

user.ascx.cs:

```
public void searchUser(QueryModel params)
{
    ...
}
```

logic is very basic but couldnt resolve it..

Comment: User controls don't typically behave as "actions" in the MVC sense - typically your action would direct to a page that hosts the user control

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid thanks for answer.understood it but how can I post it then ?

Comment: Is this on an ASP.NET WebForms site? Or are you trying to host this on something else? If the former, then this won't work - the containing page will likely already have a `<form>` element, and nested forms are not allowed.

Comment: no its visual web part.

Comment: For SharePoint?

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid yes of course, I am developing this app in sp

Comment: You might get more help tagging this SharePoint or moving it to our SharePoint.stackexchange.com site.